# Всплывающая панель навигации Safari (IOS) перекрывает футер, делая его недоступным. Как ее убрать?

Tags: javascript, css

При тестировании сайта на iphone в Safari обнаружил, что все ссылки/кнопки в нижней части экрана недоступны пользователю, т.к. тап по нижней области экрана вызывает всплытие навигационного меню Safari.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то заставить панель Safari не появляться или иным способом сделать ссылки в футере доступными?

Дать футеру отступ снизу - это не решение, т.к. панель Safari обычно скрыта, и появляется только при тапе.

зы: Понимаю, тут принято размещать код попыток решить проблему, но я в совершенной растерянности и даже не знаю откуда начать. Полагаю что либо все оставляют этот вопрос как есть, либо существует какой грязный хак, но гугление ничего не дало.

Comment: посмотрите здесь - https://benfrain.com/the-ios-safari-menu-bar-is-hostile-to-web-apps-discuss/

Comment: @soledar10 спасибо, но там нет решения, люди обсуждают webapp насколько я понял, а у меня обычный сайт.

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. В итоге вы как-то решили эту проблему?

Comment: @MiMEKiZ к сожалению сейчас не могу сказать, что какие-то мои действия что-то поменяли или я что-то действительно сделал. Т.ч. можно сказать, что нет. Возможно поведение safari поменялось и жалобы пользователей прекратились. Сейчас нет какой-либо информации о проблемах.

Comment: У всех эта головная боль... я пришел к решению что нельзя ставить кнопки взаимодействия в нижней части экрана + задавать для мобилок первого экрана ограничения по типу ` height: calc(100vh - 40px); `  это если оно у вас через flex выстраивается